# How do you delete both a pointer in a vector of pointers of Objects and the Object itself?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to code an text-based adventure game builder. I have three classes: `Room`, `Object`, and my `main` class. In my `Room` class, I have a (private) vector of pointers of `Objects`: `vector<Object*> objectsInRoom`

This keeps track of all the `Objects` stored in each room. I have a function called `objects()` in the `Room` class that returns `objectsInRooms` for when I call that vector in my `main` class.

```
vector<Object*> Room::objects() {   return objectsInRoom;  }
```

In my `main` class, in my function `pickUpObject()`, I've created a vector of pointers of `Objects` called `roomObject.` I call `objects()` in the `Room` class and store the `Objects` in `objectsInRoom` (which is only accessed in the `Room` class) in `roomObject` (which is accessible in my function in `main`). I also have a vector of `Objects` called `allObjects` that stores all the items that I want to pick up from the room and carry around with me. It has a global scope.

**I want to make it so that if I pick up an item in a particular room, I add the item to `allObjects`, delete the pointer to that element in `roomObjects` (and thus the pointer to that element in `objectsInRooms` in the `Room` class), and the item itself.**

My `pickUpObject` function is: (`Room* current` just tells me what room I'm in and thus what `Objects` I have)

```
void pickUpObject(vector<Object>&allObjects, Room* current)
{
    vector<Object*>roomObjects;  int length; string name; char flag;
    roomObjects = current->objects();
    length = roomObjects.size(); 

    bool repeat = true; 
    while (repeat)
    {
        if (length == 0)
        {
            cout << "There are no objects to pick up in " << current->name() << endl;
            repeat = false; 
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "There is a ";
            for (int k = 0; k < roomObjects.size() - 1; k++)
            {
                cout << roomObjects[k]->getName();
                if (length > 2)
                    cout << ", ";
            }
            if (length > 1)
                cout << " and " << roomObjects[length - 1]->getName() << " here." << endl;
            else
                cout << roomObjects[length-1]->getName() << "." << endl;

            cout << "What object do you want to pick up?" << endl;
            cin >> name;

            //this is where the deletion happens 
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                if (name.compare(roomObjects[i]->getName()) == 0)
                {                                               
                    allObjects.push_back(*roomObjects[i]);                      
                    roomObjects.erase(roomObjects.begin() + i);
                    deleteVectorContent(roomObjects, i, i + 1); 

                }
            cout << "roomObject size = " << roomObjects.size() << endl; 
            cout << "--------------------" << endl; 
            cout << "allObject size = " <<  allObjects.size() << endl; 
            for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.size(); i++)
                cout << allObjects[i].getName() << endl; 


            for (int i = 0; i < roomObjects.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << roomObjects[i]->getName() << endl; 
            }

            cout << "Do you want to pick up another object? (Y/N): "; 
            cin >> flag; 
            if (flag == 'N')
                repeat = false; 
        }
    }


}
```

I've looked up various posts on StackOverflow to try and resolve my dilemma. In `main`, I've created a method called `deleteVectorContent` to try and delete the pointer.

```
void deleteVectorContent(vector<Object*> objectVector, int start, int stop)
{
    for (int k = start; k < stop; k++)
        delete objectVector[k];
    objectVector.clear(); 
}
```

I've also tried 'roomObjects.remove()' to remove the item itself from that room. Whenever I compile, however, my compiler also throws me an exception. Help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. The link to this assignment is [here](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~mcs172/Sp02/Assignments/HW6/index.html). If you scroll down to the "Extra Credit for the Programming Assignment" and go to the first one marked "10 points," that is what I am working on. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Room::objects()` is returning a *copy* of `objectsInRoom`, so any modifications that `pickUpObject()` makes to that returned vector will not be applied back to `objectsInRoom`.  You would need to make `Room::objects()` return a *reference* to `objectsInRoom` instead, eg:

```
vector<Object*>& Room::objects()
{
    return objectsInRoom;
}

void pickUpObject(vector<Object> &allObjects, Room* current)
{
    vector<Object*> &roomObjects = current->objects();
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, don't provide *direct* access to `objectsInRoom` at all.  Introduce new methods to `Room` to access/remove a given `Object*` from its `objectsInRoom`, eg:

```
int Room::numObjects()
{
    return objectsInRoom.size();
}

Object* Room::getObject(int index)
{
    return objectsInRoom[index];
}

Object* Room::takeObject(int index)
{
    Object *obj = objectsInRoom[index];
    objectsInRoom.erase(objectsInRoom.begin()+index);
    return obj;
}

void pickUpObject(vector<Object> &allObjects, Room* current)
{
    int length = current->numObjects();
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (name == current->getObject(i)->getName())
        {                                               
            Object *obj = current->takeObject(i);
            allObjects.push_back(*obj);
            delete obj;
            break;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that `allObjects` is receiving *copies* of the actual `Object`s, not `Object*` pointers. The code you showed is leaking memory when you make a copy of `*roomObjects[i]` and then `erase()` the `Object*` at `i` without `delete`'ing the `Object` it is pointing at.  If `Object` is so easily copyable, you can save yourself a lot of headaches by simply getting rid of all the `Object*` pointers and just use `Object` everywhere:

```
class Room
{
    vector<Object> objectsInRoom;
    ...
};

int Room::numObjects()
{
    return objectsInRoom.size();
}

Object& Room::getObject(int index)
{
    return objectsInRoom[index];
}

Object Room::takeObject(int index)
{
    Object obj = objectsInRoom[index];
    objectsInRoom.erase(objectsInRoom.begin()+index);
    return obj;
}

void pickUpObject(vector<Object> &allObjects, Room* current)
{
    int length = current->numObjects();
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (name == current->getObject(i)->getName())
        {                                               
            allObjects.push_back(current->takeObject(i));
            break;
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Otherwise, don't mix `Object` with `Object*` like you are, use `Object*` everywhere.

If you have a fixed set of `Object`s for the game, I would create a global `vector<Object>` to hold them all, and then just pass around `Object*` pointers everywhere as needed.  Then you don't have to worry about cleaning up memory manually at all:

```
vector<Object> allGameObjects;
// fill as needed...

void Room::addObject(Object *obj)
{
    objectsInRoom.push_back(obj);
}

Object* Room::takeObject(int index)
{
    Object *obj = objectsInRoom[index];
    objectsInRoom.erase(objectsInRoom.begin()+index);
    return obj;
}

void pickUpObject(vector<Object*> &allObjects, Room* current)
{
    ...
    allObjects.push_back(current->takeObject(i));
    ...
}
```

If you absolutely need a `vector` that owns `Object*` pointers that have to be cleaned up before the `vector` is destroyed, consider using `vector<unique_ptr<Object>>` for that, let the compiler and STL handle the hard work for you.  If you ever find yourself having to write something like `deleteVectorContent()`, rethink your design.

Comment: Thank you for this amazingly detailed answer. My teacher only wants us to use raw pointers. When I make a reference to `objectsInRoom` in `pickUpObject`, how would I delete my vector of pointers of 'Objects'? I know you discourage a function like `deleteVectorContent` but if I were to put that in my `Room` class, would that work?